# Create new column based on NA values in other columns

Tags: r

I want to create another column based on NAs in other columns. Below is an example:

```
df <- replicate(5,rnorm(4))    
df[1,3:4] <- NA    
df[2:3,1:2] <- NA    
colnames(df)[1:5] <- c("One","Two","Three","Four","Five")   
df
      One   Two Three  Four  Five
[1,] 0.12 -0.38    NA    NA  0.10
[2,]   NA    NA -0.19 -0.14 -1.57
[3,]   NA    NA  1.01  0.22  0.27
[4,] 0.53  0.71 -0.86 -0.33 -1.01
```

Each column has fixed assigned weights:

```
weightc1 <- 0.1    
weightc2 <- 0.3    
weightc3 <- 0.2    
weightc4 <- 0.35    
weightc5 <- 0.05`
```

I want to let the NAs in each column equals to the corresponding column weights. E.g. NAs in column 1 is 0.1.

Then, I'd like to create a another column (call it Six) which equals to the sum of NA weights. For instance, the first row of the 6th column should be 0.55 (0.2+0.35). The last row, which has no NAs, equals to 0. The column should look like this:

```
df2 <- cbind(df, Six = c("0.55","0.4","0.4","0"))
df2
     One                 Two                  Three                Four                 Five                Six   
[1,] "0.123127305724018" "-0.378163368890999" NA                   NA                   "0.100592613978267" "0.55"
[2,] NA                  NA                   "-0.190601356688205" "-0.136015883223294" "-1.56573577576604" "0.4" 
[3,] NA                  NA                   "1.01441506421936"   "0.220154629517149"  "0.273740027540685" "0.4" 
[4,] "0.529632731861426" "0.709285638700681"  "-0.864741163519668" "-0.327865814162575" "-1.01298096772074" "0"
```

I tried IfesleSix <- ifelse(df$One == NA, "weightc1", ""), it replaced all the numbers in the first column with NAs. I know I need to solve this problem first before applying sum function (Or is there a way around it?). Please advice. Thank you!

Comment: If you create an example with a random process (i.e. `rnorm`..) please use `?set.seed` for reproducibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result can also be obtained with a matrix-vector product:

```
weights <- c(0.1,0.3,0.2,0.35,0.05)
df2 <- cbind(df, Six=c(is.na(df) %*% weights))
#            One        Two      Three        Four       Five  Six
#[1,]  1.0103788 0.07835063         NA          NA -1.9312272 0.55
#[2,]         NA         NA  1.4426233 -0.55698776  1.0897613 0.40
#[3,]         NA         NA -0.3756296 -1.18399257  0.6567973 0.40
#[4,] -0.1799107 0.46225181  1.3530630  0.09264794 -0.3004309 0.00
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have a follow-up question. I want to create another column which equals to the sum of columns*weights. Here's what I mean:    `df2["Seven"] <- NA`    `df2$Seven <- sum(df2$One*weightc1, df2$Two*weightc2, df2$Three*weightc3, df2$Four*weightc4,  df2$Five*weightc5, is.na=T)`   It returns all NAs for column Seven. How do I get this right?

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly you can try this: `df3 <- df ; df3[is.na(df3)] <- 0; df2 <- cbind(df2,Seven=c(df3 %*% weights))`. Hope this helps. Please consider asking a separate, new question if this comment does not solve your new problem.

Answer (score 1):

We get the value of all the 'weightc' objects in a `list` (using `mget`), convert the 'df' to `data.frame`, then multiply each element of 'weightc' `list` with the corresponding column of 'df' (after converting it to a logical vector with `is.na`), and use `Reduce` to get the sum.

```
Reduce(`+`,Map(function(x,y) y*is.na(x), 
    as.data.frame(df), mget(ls(pattern='weightc\\d+'))))
```

---

Or we can multiply the logical matrix (`is.na(df)`) with replicated `list` of 'weightc' after `unlist`ing and do the `rowSums`.

```
rowSums(unlist(mget(ls(pattern="weightc\\d+"))[col(df)])*is.na(df))
#[1] 0.55 0.40 0.40 0.00
```